# R combining recorded plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reasons, I have 2 ggplots recorded in 2 variables and I want to combine them into one. Is there a way to do that? Layout(), par(), nor grid.arrange() works for me.

Reasons:
 - I wanted to have 2 ggplots with additional second y-axes.
 - I used some workaround to create the second y-axis, because there is no straighforward way to do that (as I have found).
 - But the (?) object that creates the second axis is somehow not stored in the ggplot itself, therefore I was not able to have 2 different second axis, because anytime a created new one for the next ggplot, the previous was overwritten as well.
 - The only thing I was able to do was to save each ggplot right after its creation and therefore I run into the problem asked - how to combine the 2 recorded plots into one.

My code with some dummy data:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

# data
datasety <- c("SP500", "DAX")
R <- c("R1","R2")
k <- length(datasety)
Date =  seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-07-01"), by="days")
n = length(Date)
R1 <- data.frame(
  Date,
  logreturn = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
  price = 1000+seq(n) + rnorm(n, 0, 100)
)
R2 <- data.frame(
  Date,
  logreturn = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
  price = 10000+seq(n) + rnorm(n, 0, 100)
)

# standardize prices
adj_var <- function(rada, fit)
{
  max_rada <- max(rada)
  min_rada <- min(rada)
  max_fit <- max(fit)
  min_fit <- min(fit)
  ratio <- (max_fit-min_fit)/(max_rada-min_rada)
  var <- rada*ratio
  offset <- min(fit)-min(var)
  var2 <- var + offset
  return(list(ratio=ratio, offset=offset, var=var2))
}

# plots
my.plots <- vector(k, mode='list')
for (i in 1:k) {
  eval(parse(text=paste("a <- ", R[i], sep="")))

  b <- ggplot(a, aes(x=Date, y=logreturn))
  b <- b + ggtitle(datasety[i]) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  b <- b + geom_bar(data=a, aes(Date, ifelse(logreturn>0, logreturn, NA), group=1), fill="green", colour="green4", stat="identity")
  b <- b + geom_bar(data=a, aes(Date, ifelse(logreturn<=0, -logreturn, NA), group=1), fill="red", colour="red4", stat="identity")
  b <- b + geom_line(aes(Date, adj_var(price, abs(logreturn))$var), colour="blue", size=1.1, alpha = .6)
  b <- b + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / adj_var(a$price, abs(a$logreturn))$ratio - adj_var(a$price, abs(a$logreturn))$offset / adj_var(a$price, a$logreturn)$ratio, name = "price"))
  b <- b + theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(colour="blue"), axis.text.y.right = element_text(colour="blue"))

  plot(b)

  eval(parse(text=paste("my.plots[[", i, "]] <- recordPlot()", sep=""))) 
}

# how to arrange these two plots into one?
my.plots[[1]]
my.plots[[2]]
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Pls post your data and code. Thanks!

Comment: code and data included

Comment: done, i am sorry

Comment: That is some really interesting code for generating your graphs . . . I assume you're coming from another language?

Comment: I would normally use `cowplot` or `girdExtra` packages for this issue.  There seems to be some issue in how you made your ggplots that keeps throwing up an error.

Comment: I am actually not. If you mean the piecewise structure, I think it is quite common regarding ggplots. If you mean ploting and recording, the only reason why I am doing it is the fact, that I did not find any other way to embed the second y axis to the plot, so it would not change after generating the next plot.